# Python-How to read and write to a single cell

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have an excel file, importing as a dataframe.  I want to use python to find matches found in the same row of the dataframe that are no more than 0.0002 difference.  The rules are:

- Start at column 15/row 1
- Compare that value to column 16/row 1.  Continue increasing the column number and comparing the new value to column 15/row 1.  Loops until either a match is found or reaches the last column (which in my data is 125)
- If it finds 2 numbers with a delta no more than 0.0002, it will continue to the next column/row 1 and will see if there is a third number that has a delta no more than 0.0002.
- If it finds 3 numbers, then it will continue to the next column to search if there is a fourth number that has a delta no more than 0.0002.
- If a fourth match is found and will not continue searching against the starting column.  It will now progress to the next starting column (explained below)
- If any match is found, it will place the Median of the numbers rounded to 0.0000 (if 2 matches, median of two numbers; if 3 matches median of three numbers; etc.) in a new column to the right of the existing data.
- If any match is found, then the starting point (was column 15/1) will now move to column 16/1 and the process will repeat as described above.  The goal with continuing is to see if there is another set of numbers that match.
- when the starting point column reaches the end, then it goes to the next row.

I am trying to find the right code so I can get the value in row 1 column 1 and then compare it to the other values.  Will this work?

```
 df.iat[RowNum, ColNum]
```

When I find a match, I created four holding columns for each type of match (2, 3, or 4, which means 12 columns).  Because each row will have a varying number of matches (or no matches), but for future analysis purposes, I need these to be located in defined column locations to reference.  That is why I was planning on have four for each type of match.

For this piece of code, since I know the column name, I was looking to use column name and then use the row number integer to find the right location to enter the value.  Is this correct (I concatenate the column name because there are four holding columns for each match end in 1, 2, 3, 4.  This is in case there is more than one match found on a row, then I have multiple columns to hold the matches)?

```
df[ColumnName + str(3)].iloc[RowNum]
```

I tried to figure out how to get a single 'cell' by using integers (like Cells() in excel, but not sure if right way todo it.  The documentation on .loc and .iloc talks about gathering rows of data, not a sincel 'cell'.

Here is a sample of the dataframe (Due to width space, I only showed the first column of each match type (excel TwoMatch2, because that row had 2 times it matched different numbers, but there is four in total for each).

```
     High     Low    Open    Close  TwoMatch1 TwoMatch2...ThrMatch1...ForMatch1
0   1.11165 1.11128 1.11137 1.11165 1.1117
1   1.11165 1.11139 1.11148 1.11165
2   1.11167 1.11138 1.11166 1.11138 1.1117     1.1114
3   1.11165 1.11144 1.11165 1.11163 1.1117
4   1.11165 1.11149 1.1115  1.11165
5   1.11165 1.1115  1.11163 1.11163 1.1116                 1.1116
6   1.11165 1.11159 1.11159 1.11159 1.1116                 1.1116     1.1116
```

When the code finishes, it write the dataframe back to Excel, csv or database (working on replacing excel and using a database instead).  It will have the original data plus the new columns which contain the matches for each row.

Here is the code I have developed, to which I need the above formulas to finalize (in case it helps to know my intentions):

```
 df.reindex(columns = df.columns.tolist() + ['TwoRBs1','TwoRBs2','TwoRBs3','TwoRBs4','ThrRBs1','ThrRBs2','ThrRBs3','ThrRBs4','ForRBs1','ForRBs2','ForRBs3','ForRBs4'])
    
    RowNum = 0
    ttlcount = 5
    OneMinGroupFlag = 0
    FiveMinGroupFlag = 0
    FifteenMinGroupFlag = 0
    SixtyMinGroupFlag = 0
    TwoFortyMinGroupFlag = 0
    ColValues = 0
    
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    #----------------------------------------------------------------Functions-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    def AssignMinGroup(ColmnNum):
        """ If the column or a match was found in the group, then it sets the flag to not check that group again """
        nonlocal OneMinGroupFlag
        nonlocal FiveMinGroupFlag
        nonlocal FifteenMinGroupFlag
        nonlocal SixtyMinGroupFlag
        nonlocal TwoFortyMinGroupFlag
        
        if (ColmnNum >= 14 and ColmnNum <= 19)  or  (ColmnNum >= 44 and ColmnNum <= 59): OneMinGroupFlag = 1
        elif  (ColmnNum >= 20 and ColmnNum <= 25)  or  (ColmnNum >= 60 and ColmnNum <= 75): FiveMinGroupFlag = 1
        elif  (ColmnNum >= 26 and ColmnNum <= 31)  or  (ColmnNum >= 76 and ColmnNum <= 91): FifteenMinGroupFlag = 1
        elif  (ColmnNum >= 32 and ColmnNum <= 37)  or  (ColmnNum >= 92 and ColmnNum <= 107): SixtyMinGroupFlag = 1
        elif  (ColmnNum >= 38 and ColmnNum <= 43)  or  (ColmnNum >= 108 and ColmnNum <= 123): TwoFortyMinGroupFlag = 1
    def FilterGroups(ColmnNum):
        nonlocal OneMinGroupFlag
        nonlocal FiveMinGroupFlag
        nonlocal FifteenMinGroupFlag
        nonlocal SixtyMinGroupFlag
        nonlocal TwoFortyMinGroupFlag
        """"Determines if it is about to test a group that is to be filtered, then sets flag to filter this and go to the next colum/step number"""
        if ColmnNum == 44 or ColmnNum == 45 or ColmnNum == 60 or ColmnNum == 61 or ColmnNum == 76 or ColmnNum == 77 or ColmnNum == 92 or ColmnNum == 93 or ColmnNum == 108 or ColmnNum == 109: return(True)
        if OneMinGroupFlag == 1 and ((ColmnNum >= 14 and ColmnNum <= 19) or (ColmnNum >= 44 and ColmnNum <= 59)): return(True)
        elif FiveMinGroupFlag == 1 and ((ColmnNum >= 20 and ColmnNum <= 25) or (ColmnNum >= 60 and ColmnNum <= 75)): return(True)
        elif FifteenMinGroupFlag == 1 and ((ColmnNum >= 26 and ColmnNum <= 31) or (ColmnNum >= 76 and ColmnNum <= 91)): return(True)
        elif SixtyMinGroupFlag == 1 and ((ColmnNum >= 32 and ColmnNum <= 37) or (ColmnNum >= 92 and ColmnNum <= 107)): return(True)
        elif TwoFortyMinGroupFlag == 1 and ((ColmnNum >= 38 and ColmnNum <= 43) or (ColmnNum >= 108 and ColmnNum <= 123)): return(True)
        else: return(False)
    def CheckLogMatch(ColumnName,MatchValue):
        nonlocal RowNum
        """"Will check if the match has already been found, if not, then it will log it into the next available column for match type."""
        if abs(df.loc[RowNum, [ColumnName + str(1)]] - MatchValue) <= 0.00029:
            if abs(df.loc[RowNum, [ColumnName + str(2)]] - MatchValue) <= 0.00029:
                if abs(df.loc[RowNum, [ColumnName + str(3)]] - MatchValue) <= 0.00029:
                    if abs(df.loc[RowNum, [ColumnName + str(4)]] - MatchValue) <= 0.00029:
                        pass
                    else: df.loc[RowNum,[ColumnName + str(4)]] = MatchValue
                else: df.loc[RowNum, [ColumnName + str(3)]] = MatchValue
            else: df.loc[RowNum,[ColumnName + str(2)]] = MatchValue
        else: df.loc[RowNum, [ColumnName + str(1)]] = MatchValue
    def Find234Matches():
        """"Checks subsequent columns and compares to ColNum to find if there are 2, 3, or 4 matches to ColNum.  Then it enters the matches in the table"""
        nonlocal ColNum
        nonlocal RowNum
        nonlocal ColValues
        TwoStep = ColNum + 1
        while TwoStep <= 123:
            if FilterGroups(TwoStep):
                TwoStep += 1
                continue
            else:
                Step2Val = df.iat[RowNum, TwoStep]
                if abs(ColValues - Step2Val) <= 0.00029:
                    occur2 = round(median([ColValues, Step2Val]), 4)
                    AssignMinGroup(TwoStep)
                    
                    ThreeStep = TwoStep + 1
                    while ThreeStep <= 123:
                        if FilterGroups(ThreeStep):
                            if ThreeStep == 123:
                                CheckLogMatch('TwoRBs',occur2)
                                return
                            else:
                                ThreeStep += 1
                                continue
                        else:
                            Step3Val = df.iat[RowNum, ThreeStep]
                            if abs(ColValues - Step3Val) <= 0.00029:
                                occur3 = round(median([ColValues, Step2Val, Step3Val]), 4)
                                AssignMinGroup(ThreeStep)
                                
                                FourStep = ThreeStep + 1
                                while FourStep <= 123:
                                    if FilterGroups(FourStep):
                                        if FourStep == 123:
                                            CheckLogMatch('ThrRBs',occur3)
                                            CheckLogMatch('TwoRBs',occur2)
                                            return
                                        else:
                                            FourStep += 1
                                            continue
                                    else:                                    
                                        Step4Val = df.iat[RowNum, FourStep]
                                        if abs(ColValues - Step4Val) <= 0.00029:
                                            occur4 = round(median([ColValues, Step2Val, Step3Val, Step4Val]), 4)
                                            CheckLogMatch('ForRBs',occur4)
                                            CheckLogMatch('ThrRBs',occur3)
                                            CheckLogMatch('TwoRBs',occur2)
                                            return
                                        else:
                                            if FourStep == 123:
                                                CheckLogMatch('ThrRBs',occur3)
                                                CheckLogMatch('TwoRBs',occur2)
                                                return
                                            else: FourStep += 1
                            else:
                                if ThreeStep == 123:
                                    CheckLogMatch('TwoRBs',occur2)
                                    return
                                else: ThreeStep += 1
                else: TwoStep += 1           
    
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#   
    while RowNum <= ttlcount:
        ColNum = 14        
        while ColNum <= 107:            
            ColValues = df.iat[RowNum, ColNum]
            if pd.isnull(ColValues) or ColValues > df.iat[RowNum, 9] or ColValues < df.iat[RowNum, 10]: 
                ColNum += 1
                continue
            else:
                if ColNum == 44 or ColNum == 45 or ColNum == 60 or ColNum == 61 or ColNum == 76 or ColNum == 77 or ColNum == 92 or ColNum == 93 or ColNum == 108 or ColNum == 109:
                    ColNum += 1
                    continue
                else:
                    AssignMinGroup(ColNum)
                    Find234Matches()
                    ColNum +=  1
        RowNum += 1
```

Comment: Broadly speaking, you shouldn't iterate a DataFrame to update its values. A method referred to as 'broadcasting' should be used. That aside, please clarify the use case, as there might be a more efficient approach.

Comment: Here are the docs for [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) which are used to access DataFrame 'cells'.

Comment: I have a dataframe that is imported with numbers.  I need to find matches when numbers are no more than 0.0002 in that row.  So I am scanning 1 colum by column and comparing the values.  Then if a match is found, put that number in the cell of a specific column (which is my second question,

Comment: Yes, I read those documents.  I was not able to find my answer and got more confused.  They only refer to getting at the whole row of data, as far as I could tell.

Comment: Excellent. please update the *question* to include 1) This new information (i.e. your requirements) and 2) a sample of the dataset (as text, not an image). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you please also provide the expected output? (Apologies, I should have mentioned this earlier.)

Comment: Questions: 1) Does the ‘match finder’ progress to the next column *only* if a match is found, or are all columns to be compared to the start column, regardless of the number of matches found? 2) Are matches limited to four, or can you have 100 matches in a row? 3) Please provide an expected output dataset, based on the sample dataset above; and expand the sample dataset if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The first formula is:
`dataframe.iat[RowNumber, ColNumber]`

The second one is:
`dataframe['ColumnName'].values[RowNum]`

Answer (score 0):

[ answer in progress - working with OP to understand expected output ]

Have look at the output below and determine if this meets your requirements.

#### (Inferred) Requirements:

- Compare each 'High' column to 'Low', 'Open' and 'Close'
- Calculate the absolute delta
- If <= 0.0002 output the delta into a new column (.e.g 'HighLow')
- If > 0.0002, output None

#### Sample Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

cols = [('High', i) for i in df.columns[1:]]

for a, b in cols:
    df[a+b] = np.where((df[a] - df[b]).abs() <= 0.0002, (df[a] - df[b]).abs(), None)
```

#### Output:

```
      High      Low     Open    Close  HighLow HighOpen HighClose
0  1.11165  1.11128  1.11137  1.11165     None     None         0
1  1.11165  1.11139  1.11148  1.11165     None  0.00017         0
2  1.11167  1.11138  1.11166  1.11138     None    1e-05      None
3  1.11165  1.11144  1.11165  1.11163     None        0     2e-05
4  1.11165  1.11149  1.11150  1.11165  0.00016  0.00015         0
5  1.11165  1.11150  1.11163  1.11163  0.00015    2e-05     2e-05
6  1.11165  1.11159  1.11159  1.11159    6e-05    6e-05     6e-05
```

Comment: Sorry I did not realize you would go so far to help me. Thanks!  My situation is more complex.  I gave part of the situation to help know why I was needing to reference a cell by index number.  I look for 2 matches, the output is the median of those two numbers rounded to 0.0000.  Next, after 2 matches found, then looking if a third value also matches the already found 2, and then for a fourth.  If any match is found, then the starting point moves to the next column number and repeats the process to see if there is another number with matches in row.  Should I post my code as an answer below?

Comment: No worries, sounds like an interesting scenario.  Update the question please, with full requirements (bullet list), and expected output.  I’ll see what I can knock together.  (Aside, I’ve upvoted your questions, so you can upvote answers now).